# Lua list of objects

Tags: json, lua

I am very new to Lua and am in need of assistance. I am trying to create a list of objects that have a name and a message. I need to be able to send JSON to my app like:

```
{{"name":"Joe","Message":"This is a test"),{....}}
```

From what I've read this could be accomplished with tables, but it does not seem to be working, what I have tried so far is

```
message = {}
messages = {}

message["name"] = "Joe"
message["message"] = "This is a Message"

messages["1"] = ??  <--- I don't know what to do here
```

Comment: Lua is a proper name, not an acronym. No need for the ALL CAPS.

Comment: Admittedly, my JSON is a bit rusty, but that seems to be invalid JSON. Could you correct it?

Comment: That is very invalid JSON and probably the source of your confusion :)

Comment: I'm sorry i miss typed the json

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you fix your JSON code, which should probably look something like `{{"name":"Joe","Message":"This is a test"},{....}}`, you can use the following code:

```
message = {name = "Joe", Message = "This is a Message"} -- capitalization in "Message" may matter
messages = {}
messages[1] = message
```

This is the same as:

```
message = {}
message["name"] = "Joe" -- or message.name = "Joe"
message["Message"] = "This is a Message" -- or message.Message = "...."
messages = {}
messages[1] = message -- the value of that element is a table
```

Note that I used `[1]` and not `["1"]`, which are two different keys. Given your structure, you do want to use `[1]`.

Comment: Also, this is Lua, you can write `message.name` and `message.Message` instead of `message["name"]` and `message["Message"]`. And you should probably write `local message = {}` and `local messages = {}`.

Comment: @catwell: right, I mentioned .name and .Message as a comment in the example.